# The boundary of the unit cube as a topological manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

I have gotten stuck at a problem concerning the boundary of the unit cube as a topological manifold.

[image]

The problem here lies with b). I tried to do this by contradiction. Suppose that $C$ is a (2-dimensional) smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Consider the point $p=(0,0,0)$. Then $C$ looks like the graph of a function around $p$. More precisely there is an open set $W \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $p \in W$ and an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $W\cap C=\{(x,f(x)) \mid  x \in U \}$ for some smooth function $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$. Intuitively, $f$ shouldn't be smooth at $p$ because the three edges spanned by the unit vectors $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$ that meet in $p$ generate a kink, so the limits of the difference quotients along the three edges shouldn't agree at $p$.

In order to formalize this I tried to define a path that "goes around" the corner

$$
\gamma: [-\varepsilon,\varepsilon] \to U, \ 
\gamma(t)=\begin{cases}
(-t,0) , t<0 \\
(0,t) , t \geq 0
\end{cases}
$$

and consider the limits from the right and from the left

$$
\lim_{t \to 0^+}\frac{f(\gamma(t))-f(\gamma(0))}{t}
=\lim_{t \to 0^+}\frac{f((0,t))-f(0,0)}{t} \\
\lim_{t \to 0^-}\frac{f(\gamma(t))-f(\gamma(0))}{t}
=\lim_{t \to 0^-}\frac{f((-t,0))-f(0,0)}{t}.
$$

In order to find a contradiction I have to show that the limits don't agree so that the tangent of $f \circ \gamma$ doesn't exist. But I do not see how to do this since the function $f$ is smooth by assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By contradiction, if $C$ were a smooth submanifold, it would have to be two dimensional, and thus $T_0C$ would be a two dimensional vector space. But the three paths
$$
\gamma_i \colon t \in [0,1] \mapsto t e_i \in C
$$
are smooth, where $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ is the canonical basis of $\Bbb R^3$. Thus, $\gamma_i'(0) \in T_0 C$. Since $\gamma'_i(0) = e_i$, this is in contradiction with the fact that $\dim T_0C = 2$.

Answer (score 0):

If you have $M\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ a two dimensional smooth manifold, then for every $m\in M$, there exists a neighborhood of $V$ $m$ such that $M\cap V$ is the graph of a (smooth function)  $(x,y, \phi(x,y))$, or $(x, \psi(x,z), z)$, or $(\eta(y,z), y, z)$. But for points $m$ on an edge, such a thing is not possible, the boundary of the cube is not locally a graph of a function. Such an approach is also useful to show that say a $C^1$ manifold is not a $C^2$ manifold, or similar.

In this particular problem, the answer of @Didier is the better one.